# how to place gridview in another gridview using asp.net,c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

my Requirement is I have Two grid views in my web page with retrieving different tables but data is same columns also same.. Now i need show those two grid view values into single gridview..
please help...

Answer (score 1):

Select the gridview, and then click on the white arrow on top of grid and select columns.
Then select the column you want to place the new grid view inside, and at the button of the box click "convert to template". if the column does not exist just add a new template column to the gridview. press ok and close this box
now right click on the gridview and select templates and choose your column, you'll see the templated column and you can place your new gridview inside the data template.